# Exporting React Native UI components for use in current Android/iOS apps?

Tags: android, ios, swift, android-layout, react-native

( I'm not quite sure if this question is suitable for SO, but here it goes: )

I have a noob question regarding using React Native with current Android/iOS apps.

Is possible to export React Native UI components ( bootstrap style or something ) such that iOS/Android developers ( who are developing in XCode/Swift/Java )?

If this can be done, what's a good way to about it?

If not, why is it the case?

Comment: I didn't got your question. React-native have already exported components. If you are taking about custom components then yes.

Comment: Hi yes, I am referring to custom components. For example, Lists with custom CSS and so on.

Comment: Yes you can. Make a repository of your custom components. After that create a factory that will return the specific component. Your component should be customizable  enough so that developer can place them anywhere in his view

Comment: @JagadishUpadhyay wow cool. I was wondering if there's any examples ? Quite lost here. U the MAN.

Comment: You can visit https://www.decosoftware.com/. Its an IDE for MAC